# How can I adjust the fonts and sizes of bullets in org superstar?

Tags: fonts, emacs, org-mode, bullet

By starting (Gnu/vanilla) Emacs with the `.emacs` at the bottom of this file I get

1. headings and subheadings that use larger fonts, obviating the need to typeset into HTML or LaTeX for pleasant reading, and
2. improved fonts for bullets.

[image: superstar 1]

But there are two problems:

3. the height of the bullet is larger than the heading, and
4. the bullets are similar, unlike what the
   [reference page](https://github.com/integral-dw/org-superstar-mode)
   promises.

[image: superstar 2]

How can I adjust the fonts and sizes of bullets in org superstar?

I'm on macOS Ventura. You'll need to adjust `Monaco` below to your favorite font to start with this `.emacs`.

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(background-color . "black"))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(foreground-color . "white"))
(blink-cursor-mode 0)

(defvar org-startup-indented)
(setq org-startup-indented t)
(defvar org-indent-indentation-per-level)
(setq org-indent-indentation-per-level 4)

(set-frame-font "Monaco 32")

(require 'org-superstar)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (org-superstar-mode 1)))

(custom-set-faces
  '(org-level-1 ((t (:inherit outline-1 :height 2.0))))
  '(org-level-2 ((t (:inherit outline-2 :height 1.5))))
  '(org-level-3 ((t (:inherit outline-3 :height 1.2))))
  '(org-level-4 ((t (:inherit outline-4 :height 1.0))))
  '(org-level-5 ((t (:inherit outline-5 :height 1.0))))
  )
```

Comment: The faces used are documented: https://github.com/integral-dw/org-superstar-mode#custom-faces